# The probability of winning a game

Tags: probability

Sam plays a game with two fair spinners , spinner A can land on $2$ , $3$ , $5$ or $7$ , spinner B can land on $2$ , $3$ , $4$ , $5$ or $6$ . Sam spins both spinners .
He wins the game if one spinner lans on odd number and the lands on even number , he plays the game twice .

Find the probability that Sam wins both times .

My attempt:

P(win both times) = ($\frac{3}{4} \times \frac{3}{5} + \frac{1}{4} \times \frac{2}{5}$ )$\times 4 $

Is it correct ?

Comment: Did you actually compute that?  Is it $<1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not correct. Multiplication by $4$ is incorrect. If you do not multiply by $4$, that gives you the probability of winning a game. We assume each game is an independent event and probability of winning or losing a game is independent of others.

Probability of a win, $ P(W) = \frac{3}{4} \times \frac{3}{5} + \frac{1}{4} \times \frac{2}{5} = \frac{11}{20}$

As both games are independent events,

$P(WW) = \frac{11}{20} \cdot \frac{11}{20} = \frac{121}{400}$